# How to create a function and trigger to create a new partition when needed in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tests.partitioned_table (
    partition_id int4 NOT NULL,
    dummy text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT partitioned_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (partition_id)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (partition_id);
```

and want to create a function that will create a new partition automatically if I try to insert a row with a partition_id that has no matching partition.

I've tried the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_and_insert_partitioned_table() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      partition TEXT;
    BEGIN
      partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || new.partition_id::text;
      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition) THEN
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition || ' partition of ' || TG_RELNAME || ' for values in (' || new.partition_id|| ');';
      END IF;
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || partition || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* RETURNING partition_id;';
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $BODY$
     language plpgsql
```

With the following trigger:

```
create trigger auto_partition_partitioned_table
before insert on tests.partitioned_table 
for each row execute procedure create_partition_and_insert_partitioned_table();
```

However when I try to insert into the table I get an error

```
' ERROR: no partition of relation "partitioned_table" found for row'
```

If I try to insert a row into the table that already has a partition I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [55006]: ERROR: cannot CREATE TABLE .. PARTITION OF "partitioned_table_123" because it is being used by active queries in this session
  Where: SQL statement "CREATE TABLE partitioned_table_123_123 partition of partitioned_table_123 for values in (123);"
PL/pgSQL function create_partition_and_insert_partitioned_table() line 7 at EXECUTE
```

I suspect that when I run a query such as the one that generated the above error:

```
insert into tests.partitioned_table values (123, 'tete');
```

"tests.partitioned_table" is being replaced by "tests.partitioned_table_123" before the trigger is fired and the function runs but I don't know how I could avoid this.

Another idea I had was that perhaps I could trigger the function when the "no partition for relation" error is thrown, but I am not sure how I could do that either.

Any and all help is appreciated!!

Comment: "BEFORE ROW triggers on INSERT cannot change which partition is the final destination for a new row." [5.11. Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html), 5.11.2. Declarative Partitioning, 5.11.2.3. Limitations. I eventually used partitioning using inheritance and it worked. But I didn't succeed with a RANGE (declarative partitioning).

Answer (score 3):

For your trigger try something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_and_insert_partitioned_table() RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$
    DECLARE
      partition TEXT;
    BEGIN
      partition := TG_RELNAME || '_' || new.partition_id::text;
      IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname=partition) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'A partition has been created %',partition;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || partition || ' partition of ' || TG_RELNAME || ' for values in (' || new.partition_id|| ');';


      END IF;
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || partition || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* returning partition_id;';
      RETURN NULL;
    END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note: the if not exists is selecting from pg_class.